# How to test Table and it's content in protractor?

Tags: testing, protractor

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K840.png) is HTML of  table content and i want to test this HTML tags

```html
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'date'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                Date-Time
              </a>
    </td>
    <td><a>Amount</a>
    </td>
    <td><a>Transaction Type</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>


  <!-- ngRepeat: tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end -->
  <tr id="anchor0" ng-repeat="tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end" class="ng-scope">
    <td class="ng-binding">Dec 8, 2016 4:44:43 PM</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">210</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">Credit</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end -->
  <tr id="anchor1" ng-repeat="tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end" class="ng-scope">
    <td class="ng-binding">Dec 8, 2016 4:45:08 PM</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">100</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">Debit</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end -->
  <tr id="anchor2" ng-repeat="tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end" class="ng-scope">
    <td class="ng-binding">Dec 13, 2016 10:54:03 AM</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">1000</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">Credit</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end -->
  <tr id="anchor3" ng-repeat="tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end" class="ng-scope">
    <td class="ng-binding">Dec 13, 2016 10:54:05 AM</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">32</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">Credit</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end -->
  <tr id="anchor4" ng-repeat="tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end" class="ng-scope">
    <td class="ng-binding">Dec 13, 2016 10:54:10 AM</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">155</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">Debit</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end -->
  <tr id="anchor5" ng-repeat="tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end" class="ng-scope">
    <td class="ng-binding">Dec 13, 2016 10:54:12 AM</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">12</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">Debit</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end -->
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what do you want to test in it? and put your html of this table

Comment: column value ..I added screenshot of table but don't know why it's not showing

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: @Danny Thanks for the link .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case table is generated using repeater, you can write loop to get rows and then columns present in that.

For example:

```js
element.all(by.repeater('row in rows')).then(function(rows){
 rows.forEach(function(row){
  row.all(by.repeater('column in row.columns')).then(function(columns){
       /* your code here
          navigate columns using columns[]
       */
  });
 });
});
```

Edit:

```js
element.all(by.repeater('tx in transactions')).then(function(rows){
    rows.forEach(function(row){
        row.all(by.tagName('td')).then(function(columns){
            /* For getting text in date column*/
            columns[0].getAttribute('innerText').then(function(dateText){
                console.log('Date: ' + dateText);
            });
            /* For getting text in Amount column*/
            columns[1].getAttribute('innerText').then(function(amountText){
                console.log('Amount: ' + amountText);
            });
            /* For getting text in Transaction column*/
            columns[2].getAttribute('innerText').then(function(transactionType){
                console.log('Transaction Type: ' + transactionType);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Using above code you will able to print the grid, and you can write whatever logic you need to verify data too.

Comment: this is the website which am testing

Comment: this is my table content

Comment: @chhayavyas: I am unable to view any data in table after selecting dates. Can you tell me which date I can select for valid data to be populated?

Comment: Dates are non clickable ..whatever content table has that i want to test

Comment: Can you post the table html with valid rows, as I am not able to see any data in table, I am not sure what repeaters it is using.

Comment: @chhayavyas: I have added code in the answer, please take a look into this. And if it answers your question, please select it as correct answer.

Comment: way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/banking/#/listTx                                           this is the website which i am testing you can check there valid rows as i am new I don't know much more about that and yes it is answer of my question Thanks @rk30

Comment: Thank you .it's big help for me

Comment: can you help me to test hyperlink ?

Comment: Yes, please open another question for it. It will be better.

Comment: the above answer just passing the test but not showing rows value

Comment: please check it now, I have verified it on my local and it is working.
Changed getText() to getAttribute('innerText')

Comment: It's not working in my local. can you tell where are  you  seeing console.log output ?

Comment: I want to get rows value .  I am getting column values and it is working fine .

Comment: You can check if repeater is returning any valid rows using rows.length.
it will run for the number of rows available. If no rows are retrieved, it will not enter inside loop.

Comment: Yes ,it is not entering inside the loop