# How to get first row value from table?

Tags: protractor, automated-tests

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'date'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
            Date-Time
          </a>
        </td>
        <td><a>Amount</a></td>
        <td><a>Transaction Type</a></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>


      <!-- ngRepeat: tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end --><tr id="anchor0" ng-repeat="tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">Dec 8, 2016 4:44:43 PM</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">210</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Credit</td>
      </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end --><tr id="anchor1" ng-repeat="tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">Dec 8, 2016 4:45:08 PM</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">100</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Debit</td>
      </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end --><tr id="anchor2" ng-repeat="tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">Dec 13, 2016 10:54:03 AM</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">1000</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Credit</td>
      </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end --><tr id="anchor3" ng-repeat="tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">Dec 13, 2016 10:54:05 AM</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">32</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Credit</td>
      </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end --><tr id="anchor4" ng-repeat="tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">Dec 13, 2016 10:54:10 AM</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">155</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Debit</td>
      </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end --><tr id="anchor5" ng-repeat="tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">Dec 13, 2016 10:54:12 AM</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">12</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Debit</td>
      </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: tx in transactions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | sDate:startDate:end -->
    </tbody>

  </table>
```

This is HTML code and I want date-time amount of 1st row?

Comment: Please take a few minutes to learn the code formatting tools here, and check that the question is readable using the preview pane. Thanks.

Comment: here is the sample code

Comment: it("testing fields", function () {
 browser.get('http://www.way2automation.com');
 element.all(by.repeater('tx in transactions')).then(function (rows){
 rows.forEach(function (row) {
row.all(by.tagName('td')).then(function (columns) {                    columns[0].getAttribute('innerText').then(function (dateText) { console.log('Date: ' + dateText);});
columns[1].getAttribute('innerText').then(function (amountText){ console.log('Amount: ' + amountText);}); 
columns[2].getAttribute('innerText').then(function(transactionType){ console.log('Transaction Type: ' +transactionType);}); }); });

Comment: ^ Please add your additional code into the question, using the 'edit' feature. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below code you will be able to get date from first row:

```
element(by.repeater('tx in transactions')).element(by.tagName('td')).getAttribute('innerText').then(function(dateText){
    console.log('Date for first row is::' + dateText);
});
```

In case you want to do the same for all the rows:

```
element.all(by.repeater('tx in transactions')).then(function(rows){
    rows.forEach(function(row, index){
        row.element(by.tagName('td')).getAttribute('innerText').then(function(dateText){
            console.log('Date for ' + (index+1) + ' row is::' + dateText);
        });
    });
})
```

You may refer to the below post, in this I have written code for retrieving all the different column values:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41102952/7283782

Comment: Thank you it works...But How to check console.log output ? as browser is closing so fast